# Code for checking data and storing data running twice in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, dictionary

I just finished coding a huge block of code and even though it runs fine, the issue is that the code runs twice whenever I call the method in which the code is written. There's probably no use in copying the entire block of code, since it would only confuse you, but I can explain how the code is structured. I suspect the problem lies within the structure of the method.

```
func methodName {

    if thisConditionIsTrue {

        // This condition is true, so it gets executed: it retrieves an array of dictionaries from the database

        for-in loop {
            // This loop runs through all of the retrieved dictionary objects

            if dictionaryMeetsThisRequirement {
                // False condition, so it doesn't get executed
            else if dictionaryMeetsThisRequirement {
                // False condition, so it doesn't get executed
            else if dictionaryMeetsThisRequirement {
                // False condition, so it doesn't get executed
            else {
                // True condition, so it gets executed: now it stores data form the client into the database
```

The code is very complicated and contains a boatload of personal information, so unfortunately I can't just copy it and post it here, but I hope this simplified version of it is still understandable enough for everyone to get it. The issue I'm dealing with is that only the last part (I assume, not sure about it though) of the code gets executed twice, which means whatever I want to store inside my database gets stored twice. I also have a view transitioning happening at the end of the code, which also gets triggered twice, so basically whenever this method gets called, I see a view transitioning happening twice in like a split second. The reason I assume it only runs the last part of the code twice is because I assume it has something to do with the for-in loop (which happens somewhere halfway through the process). I figured this was the only way I could check each individual dictionary in the dictionary array that gets retrieved from the database, but the problem is that the code for storing the data in the database is written inside the for-in loop as well. So whenever the loop decides to run again (for some reason) it might execute the true "else" statement again, causing every code inside that else statement to be executed twice. Anyone who can either correct me or confirm that this might indeed be the cause of my issue? And only, if it is, can I also get some tips on the most efficient way to run through a dictionary array without using the for-in loop?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use for in loop, as dictionaries are not ordered, thats the beauty. The only thing you have to to is

1.If You want to check if a key exists in the dictionary

```
if  dictionary[keyname] != nil {
   //perform some action
}
```

2.If you want to check if a value of key is equal to some variable you are checking against

```
if  dictionary[keyname] == variableYouAreCheckingAgainst {
   //perform some action
}
```

Comment: How is this possible? I have multiple dictionaries inside an array, so how does it know which dictionary it needs to check the "keyname" value for? I honestly don't think a dictionary array is any different from any other array (string array for example). I have multiple dictionaries which all have 5 keys, but each dictionary has other values assigned to those 5 keys.

Comment: Right, would you like to give me a simple example of what the array and dictionaries contain?

Comment: you can search specific elements in an array.. eg let array["x","y","z","w"] ; if array.contains("z"){ print("it contains the element") }    .Don't iterate over an array unless you have to, i asked you for example in order to see if there is any more efficient way..

Comment: Just to set an example: the array could contain 30 dictionaries and each dictionary has the same 5 keys that every other dictionary in the array has: "first name", " last name", "date of birth", "age" and "address". This basically means that these 5 keys are in the array 30 times and each of the 30 times it contains a different value. So if I were to check it up against a variable like in your example, it would compare 1 variable to 30 different values... that's not very handy and I'm pretty sure that's not even possible.

Comment: It would be really stupid to loop through 1 dictionary, since every key-value pair inside a dictionary has a different key, so I can check each key individually. But when I have an array of multiple dictionaries, I run into the same key multiple times, forcing me to loop through the array to make sure every time I run into a key, it contains a different value.

Comment: And you think that the clever way is to do it the way you have? What would happen if you had 1million users?! My recommendation is to use on of the following: 1. You use an array of dictionaries, where each element of the array is a user's dictionary-Use a modification of the two statements i ve written in my answer to directly search the info you want-DONT iterate, its unnecessary.  2.Use a dictionary within a dictionary. 3. Use a class or struct! I would go for nr 3. You current setup is not efficient at all!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the entire code block of the `for-in` loop will be executed multiple times, once for each dictionary in the array.  If there are several dictionaries that meet the relevant criteria for the final `else` clause then, yes, it will be executed several times.  If you have code that needs to execute only once, if any of the dictionaries meet the relevant criteria, set a flag and test it after the `for-in` loop has completed:

```
if thisConditionIsTrue {

    // This condition is true, so it gets executed: it retrieves an array of dictionaries from the database
    var oneOffProcessRequired = false
    for-in loop {
        // This loop runs through all of the retrieved dictionary objects

        if dictionaryMeetsThisRequirement {
            // False condition, so it doesn't get executed
        else if dictionaryMeetsThisRequirement {
            // False condition, so it doesn't get executed
        else if dictionaryMeetsThisRequirement {
            // False condition, so it doesn't get executed
        else {
            // True condition, so it gets executed: set the flag
            oneOffProcessRequired = true
        }
    }
    if oneOffProcessRequired == true {
        // flag is true, so store data form the client into the database
    }
```

Alternatively, if you want to abandon the for-in loop as soon as one of the dictionaries meets the criteria for the final else clause, just use `break` to terminate the loop.

Also, it might help to try tracing the flow of execution by throwing in some `print` statements and/or using some breakpoints and stepping through the execution.